# How can I limit bandwidth to users on a wireless hotspot on Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, wireless-hotspot

I have a Ubuntu laptop (14.04) which is connected to the internet via Ethernet. The internet connection is shared using wireless AP on the same laptop to which mine and some friend's phones connect. I want to limit the bandwidth of all devices except mine. 
After some research I figured out that **iptables** could be modified to accomplish many tasks, along with **tc** but that was more like filtering the network.
 
https://serverfault.com/questions/70042/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc

https://serverfault.com/questions/123371/shaping-outbound-traffic-to-control-download-speeds-with-linux

But all these are like too cumbersome to understand for me which is why I am asking for a simple solution.

There are multiple ways to create hotspot, like **hostapd**, **hotspotd**, **gnome network manager**  etc. I'm looking for some generic solution using firewall or something, that can restrict bandwidth by IP or MAC addersses.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using Evillimiter.

> A tool to limit and monitor the bandwidth (upload/download) of devices connected to your network without physical or administrative access.

Visit [Evillimiter](https://github.com/bitbrute/evillimiter) github repository and install it in your ubuntu.

Installation steps are provided in the github repository. 
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate. It would be even more helpful if you mention a few lines on what it does and how it works, which doesn't make it appear like an advertisement. FWIW stack overflow refrains from promotional content.